# Detect / log network changes in rasbian/ Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I just stated using raspberrypi, trying to learn some networking and Linux stuff.

I want to log or detect network changes like:

1. If my machine joined a network.
2. If any device joined the network of my machine

I want to log these changes of the network.

Is there any log file in the file system captures those logs? Or, Is there a way I can keep track of that?

PS. since rasbian is a Linux system I want to know if this can be done in Linux.

Comment: (1) is ambiguous, if you get the link layer (ethernet on RPi) up but he network layer (IP) is not yet defined do you consider your network to be up?  (2) is not possible unless your RPi is operating as the router (and even then you cannot check on all machines if you have switches laying around in the network, which you need is you want to add more than 2 machines to a network with an RPi).